# Securing JEA (Just Enough Administration)

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

I have recently deployed a JEA endpoint on a few Domain Controllers for a user (Domain User, non privileged).
The user had to be added to "Remote Management Users" AD group in order to have the ability to Powershell into a these DCs.
It occurred to me that outside of the provided, confined endpoint, the user can create sessions to default Powershell endpoint which has access to everything.

Following the [great article](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-remoting-without-administrator-rights/#:%7E:text=Another%20purpose%20of%20the%20Remote,to%20connect%20via%20Server%20Manager.), I would have to add the user under the permissions of the default windows.powershell endpoint which isn't a straight forward process.

What would be the sensible way to confine the given user to just the one particular endpoint?

Many thanks,

Comment: You should be able to define a role on your endpoint and limit who can connect via that role.

Comment: Thank you. I think did not think this enough. You are absolutely right. I erroneously assumed that "Remote Management Users" was required for powershell